# Why doesn't C++ complain about multiple definitions of an operator function?

Tags: c++

The following code has 2 definitions of `operator+` - one is on the class `Foo`, and the other one is a standalone function.

I feel like the compiler should have complained about this, but it didn't. When I use `operator+` in the main function, it picks the one defined in the class. When I delete the one in the class, it starts using the standalone function.

The fact that deleting a class method silently changes the behavior of the C++ program is very concerning. Is there a rationale behind this?

https://ideone.com/rtfEFP

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    int operator+(const Foo& b)
    {
        return 5;
    }
};

int operator+(const Foo& a, const Foo& b)
{
    return 6;
}

int main()
{
    Foo a, b;
    int c{ a + b };
    std::wcout << c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see this as any different from the situation when one declaration shadows another, and then you remove the shadowing declaration and then BAM the program changes its meaning because the previously shadowed declaration is now visible....

Comment: What are some other examples of a declaration shadowing some other declaration?

Comment: @xskxzr Good catch!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two signatures don't really match because the first takes a non-const reference for the first operand. To  "fix" this, make it const:

```
int operator+(const Foo& b) const
```

or make the first parameter of the non-member non-const (don't do that in real code!)

```
int operator+(Foo& a, const Foo& b)
```

That will cause your code to produce an ambiguous overload compiler diagnostic.

With your original code, the member is picked, because the non-const reference matches the operands better.

Comment: It's interesting that when I remove the usage of  `operator+` in the `main()` function and add a `const` keyword to the class method, the compiler doesn't complain about the ambiguity. It only complains about the ambiguity when you actually try to use the operator.

Comment: @ShivanshuGoyal The signatures are not exactly the same (one is a member function, the other a non-member) which explains why you don't get duplicate symbol errors. And since you don't use the overload, there is no overload resolution to catch the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is analogous to overloads based on `const` and non-`const` qualifiers.

```
int operator+(const Foo& a, const Foo& b)
{
    return 6;
}
```

is like a `const` member function.

Given

```
Foo a;
Foo const b;
Foo c;

a + c; // Resolves to the non-const member function.

b + c; // Resolves to the non-member function since the first argument
       // is of type `const Foo&`.
```